# How to return a Python Enum from C extension?

Tags: python, c, enums, python-c-api

I'm writing a C extension for Python that wraps a C library. The C library has a few enum types and I've written corresponding `IntEnum`s for these, for example:

```py
from enum import IntEnum
# _enum_consts is a C extension creating Python
# constants for the library's enum constants
from . import _enum_consts

class Align(IntEnum):
    DEFAULT = _enum_consts.MD_ALIGN_DEFAULT
    LEFT = _enum_consts.MD_ALIGN_LEFT
    CENTER = _enum_consts.MD_ALIGN_CENTER
    RIGHT = _enum_consts.MD_ALIGN_RIGHT
```

Now, in the C extension where I'm wrapping the library's main functionality, some of the library functions return enum types, and I want to convert those to the Python `IntEnum` values. (I realize I could simply return the `int`s directly and they would successfully compare to `IntEnum`s, but that sort of defeats the purpose.)

The question is, how do I create the `IntEnum` values to return? All I can find are examples where the C enum constants are converted to Python constants with `PyModule_AddIntConstant()` (which is just what the `_enum_consts` extension module does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, the module with the `IntEnum` needs to be imported into the extension module (if you are not already doing that). In the module initialization function:

```c
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_someextension(void)
{
    // ...

    PyObject *m;
    m = PyModule_Create(&someextension_module);
    if (m == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // ...

    // Import the enums module, where "somepackage.enums"
    // is the full name of the enums module
    PyObject *enums = PyImport_ImportModule("somepackage.enums");
    if (enums == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(m);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_DECREF(enums);

    return m;
}
```

Then, where you want to instantiate an `IntEnum` value, first fetch the module it's in again:

```c
PyObject *enums = PyImport_AddModule("somepackage.enums");
if (enums == NULL) {
    // Return NULL, -1, etc. to signal an exception
}
```

Right after, fetch your `IntEnum` type (`Align` in this case) from the module:

```c
PyObject *align_enum = PyObject_GetAttrString(enums, "Align");
if (align_enum == NULL) {
    // Return NULL, -1, etc. to signal an exception
}
```

Then, you can create the instance you need. `align` here will be the value to fetch from the `IntEnum`. We do this by calling the type object, just as we would in regular Python (note that `PyObject_CallFunction` is not actually limited to calling functions--it can call any callable object):

```c
PyObject *align_instance = PyObject_CallFunction(align_enum, "(i)", align);
if (align_instance == NULL) {
    Py_DECREF(align_enum);
    // Return NULL, -1, etc. to signal an exception
}
```

Now, `align_instance` contains the `IntEnum` instance to return. Be sure to `Py_DECREF(align_enum)` before returning.